# Opening MATLAB scripts by double click on linux

Tags: linux, matlab

I associated  '*.m* scripts with Matlab, but still, I have a problem. When I open two files of this type, I open 'two Matlabs' also. I want to have a similar result as in Windows. I open two scripts, and I have one opened Matlab application with two scripts as tabs. How to do this?

How to properly set up double click method of opening Matlab scripts on Linux as it works on Windows?